# how to keep tag value always append and didn't replace by new value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to make a multi tag with auto suggestion and separated with comma. And
I have a problem. Everytime I click from suggestion result. It is always replace by new value.

Here is my code :

**HTML :**

```
<input type="text" id="ftags" autocomplete="off" value="" name="tags" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);">
<div id="suggestions" style="top: 26px; display: block;">
    <p id="searchresults">
        <span class="category">AirCraft</span>
            <a href="#" class="searchlink" id="data_1"><span class="searchheading" data="Ace Aviation" id="span_1">Ace Aviation</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="searchlink" id="data_2"><span class="searchheading" data=" Ackland" id="span_2"> Ackland</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="searchlink" id="data_3"><span class="searchheading" data="Adam Aircraft" id="span_3">Adam Aircraft</span></a><span class="seperator">
            <a href="" title="Sitemap">Nothing interesting here? Try the sitemap.</a>
        </span>
        <br class="break">
    </p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
function lookup(inputString) {
        if(inputString.length == 0) {
            $('#suggestions').fadeOut(); // Hide the suggestions box
        } else {
            $.post("modul/mod_album/rpc.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data) { // Do an AJAX call
                $('#suggestions').fadeIn(); // Show the suggestions box
                $('#suggestions').html(data); // Fill the suggestions box

            });
        }
}

$('.searchlink').click(function(e) {

        var parent  = $(this).closest('a').attr('id').replace('data_','');

        var val_data = $("#span_"+parent).attr('data');
        var ftag = $("#ftags").val();


       $("#ftags").val(val_data).focus();     

       e.preventDefault();

})
```

Comment: Maybe something like `$("#ftags").val($("#ftags").val() + val_data).focus()`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to add new suggestion into `input#ftags` instead of replacing previous one?

Comment: I want to add like this : Ace Aviation,  Ackland, Adam Aircraft

Answer (score 0):

This instruction replaces the content:

```
  $('#suggestions').html(data);
```

You might want to do something along these lines:

```
 // append to current content
  $('#suggestions').html(  $('#suggestions').html()+data);
```

Or, if you need some html to separate the tags,

```
  var currentTags =  $('#suggestions').html();
  if (currentTags != '')
    currentTags += ',&nbsp;';
  $('#suggestions').html( currentTags+data);
```

Answer (score 0):

consider one line of code !
`var combo = ftag + val_data ;`

```
var val_data = $("#span_"+parent).attr('data');
var ftag = $("#ftags").val();
var combo = ftag + val_data ;
$("#ftags").val(combo).focus();
```

Comment: Hi @codeiz. Thanks for help, It almost perfect, except when I typed a little : **A**
and then I picked a suggestion result (Ackland). It will be like this : AAckland (it is wrong).
I want to be like this: **Ackland** (it is correct).